# Strange bug for python lib requests

Tags: python, debugging, python-requests

Below is my code. It is strange that when I print the response.url. The result is http://192.168.2.153 instead of the whole path http://192.168.2.153/api/v1/player/pot/1
Therefore I cannot send post request to the correct url.

Can anyone help to give me some suggestions.

```
    try:
        image = {'image':img}
        data = {"source":'webcam',"person_count":1}

        response = requests.post('http://192.168.2.153/api/v1/player/pot/1')
        print(response.url)
        print(response.text)
    except:
        e = sys.exc_info()
        print(e)
```

Comment: I do not get problem when sending GET request. only POST got this problems..

Comment: This is in window 10 environment

Comment: You need to send a body with a ```POST``` request.

Comment: Please mention the exact error in the question.

Comment: Thanks, I think I figure out the reason now.
It is the server side redirecting to another path.